# What is the corresponding syntax of "not" in 8.9 version of elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

The below syntax is from 2.2 elastic version and its works fine.

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "term" : { "name.first" : "shay" }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "not" : {
                "range" : {
                    "postDate" : {
                        "from" : "2010-03-01",
                        "to" : "2010-04-01"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the corresponding syntax for **not** clause for 8.9 version since **not** is not allowed to use in latest version of elastic.
Getting parsing_exception unknown query [not] in 8.9

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a filter you can use the `must_not` so your search will become as below, also the `range` needs to be updated see the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html):

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            {
                "term" : { 
                    "name.first" : "shay" 
                }
            }
        ],
        "must_not": [
            {
                "range" : {
                    "postDate" : {
                        "gt" : "2010-03-01",
                        "lt" : "2010-04-01"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```